# How to prioritise drawing labels?

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I frequently check point coordinates for features against mapping and elevation data, which as a workflow is as simple as applying labels to the points and then using Go 2 next feature to cycle through them.

However, the label is always the last thing to render. Typically, I would want to cycle to the next feature after only some of the background context has loaded, but I need to make sure the right point is at the right feature, so have to wait until the label finally loads.

Is there any way to prioritise the draw/render of labels to be first? Or something else that that's causing the labels in this scenario to take so long to show up?

[image: Image shows 1:250k map, 8m contours, and point reference for Ant Hill all having loaded, but still waiting for the point's label to appear]

[image: and finally the label appears]